# IntelliJ IDEA: What is 'Unnecessary local variable' inspection name?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inspection, code-inspection

I want to run certain inspection on Java project. I see this inspection working in real-time in edit window. But when I use "Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name" I can't find this inspection. Actually there is one with the same name but it's for JavaScript(tried it though, not working, as expected). Can anyone tell me exact name of inspection I need or teach me how to figure it out?

Here's code sample:

```
private Integer getInteger(){
    //x on the line below will be highlighted by inspection saying
    // "Local variable 'x' is redundant more... (Ctrl+F1)"
    Integer x = 5;
    return x;
}
```

**Update:** I managed to launch needed inspection using workaround. I created test case like above, then pressed Alt+Enter on highlighted region then right arrow key and selected "Run inspection on".[image] 
This is working, but still leaves unclear how to run same inspection via "Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name"

Comment: Provide the relevant code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88443), which was fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 14.

Answer (score 2):

I get the "Local variable 'i' is redundant message" (and a "yellow" analysis) when I type this code:

```
public int testMe()
{
   int i = 5;  // The 'i' is highlighted
   return i;
}
```

I can suppress this warning (and get a "green" analysis, no warnings), by adding this annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
public int testMe()
{
   int i = 5;
   return i;
}
```

Try "Redundant Local Variable".  This seems to be the description to match the annotation, according to [this list of suppress warnings arguments](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html).

```
Warning Description         Warning Name
Redundant local variable    UnnecessaryLocalVariable
```

Comment: See my comment to Eel Lee's answer

Answer (score 2):

In my IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.5 it's called `Redundant local variable`, I think.

Your  `x` is redundant because you are not using that variable anywhere in that scope, besides returning it. And so that code

```
Integer x = 5;
return x;
```

can be simplified to

```
return 5;
```

Yet to avoid "magic numbers" like `return 5;` you could assign it to a class constant (`private static final Integer X = 5;`)

Comment: That's just a test sample, I don't have magic numbers in my real code ;). Inspection "Redundant local variable" in IDEA 12.1.6 is for JavaScript only. I can see it if press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+I and there's little JS icon on the right. I also tried to run it and it ignores Java code completely.